TypeScript Error: 'Signal<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
When attempting to assign a value of type 'Signal' to a variable of type 'boolean', TypeScript throws the error: Type 'Signal' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
I just to want assign the value of a signal which is a boolean to another variable in a standalone component.Is there any ways to simply handle this issue?
    // Auth Servive
  class AuthService {
  private isLoggedIn: WritableSignal<boolean> = signal(false);
  public isLogged = computed(() => { return this.isLoggedIn(); });

  setAuth() {
    this.isLoggedIn.set(true);
  }
}

// Login component

class LoginComponent {
  private authService: AuthComponent;

  constructor(authService: AuthComponent) {
    this.authService = authService;
  }

  someFunction() {
    // Type error occurs here:
    // 'Signal<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
    this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLogged; 
  }
}


This question lacks a bit of research! please check Angular Signals documentation or the Angular University Guide on Signals

You should read the signal value by calling that function
this.isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLogged(); 

